# Is there any tool or framework similar to Xtext for creating language-specific editors for the Intellij IDEA platform ?

Tags: intellij-idea, dsl, xtext, intellij-plugin

I have my own tool for creating textual domain-specific languages and I want to connect it to something like Xtext in order to generate IntelliJ IDEA editor for any language created by my tool. Is there any tool or maybe any other way how can I do it ?

Xtext is no longer maintained for IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: did you have a look at Language Server Protocol and what the extend is that intellij or a third party extension supports it. xtext itself does support lsp. and there is jetbrains mps but the ususal usecase there is standalone tool / language workbench

Comment: thank you for your reply. I know about LSP, but for me is actually not the most appropriate solution, rather "last option". The best solution would be that after generating parser etc., output of my tool will be an input to another tool, which generates plugin for IntelliJ IDEA, providing editor for my new language, which won't depend on any server, as in LSP case. So that's the reason, why I'm finding other tool similar to Xtext. 
JetBrains MPS is not appropriate for me, because it provides projectional, not textual editor.

Comment: JetBrains has already got a non-text DSL builder -- MPS. Try it out.

Comment: Yes I know about it, but as I wrote above, I need a tool for textual DSL.

Comment: That's difficult. Are you satisfied with Kotlin's DSL?

Comment: First of all, sorry for late reply. I didn't work with Kotlin's DSL, but I think it's not so appropriate for my purpose, because my problem is not just about generating the editor, but also about generating the whole DSL including editor, so I wanted to extend my own existing tool for it. I decided to use Xtext and LSP, as mentioned above. After a deeper analysis it looks like perfect solution for my issue, because I can use LSP in many different editors. So - thank you guys for your recommendations.